# Why do I get "Unknown column 'Jacob' in 'where clause'"?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a bit of code that retreives an users password from his username.

But when I exceute to following code I get this error

> "Unknown column 'Jacob' in 'where clause'"

My users table: https://gyazo.com/c3f9aff0e0ceea9be39ba51c4a8680f3

```
def get_passwd(user_name):
    user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name LIKE (%s)"%(user_name))
     print(user_passwd)

get_passwd('Jacob')
```

Edit: formatted code

Comment: You need single quotes around your user_name variable.  But why the heck are you storing passwords in a table like this?

Comment: "Coding today for info leaks tomorrow."

Comment: Sounds like time for a refresher from [http://bobby-tables.com](Little Bobby Tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not parameterising your query correctly, so it's passing in a literal value to the SQL instead of enclosing it in string quotes. Also a `LIKE` value doesn't need brackets round it.

The correct way to use the execute method is as follows - passing the value in as a parameter, instead of doing a string interpolation:

```
def get_passwd(user_name):
    user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name LIKE %s", ('%' + user_name + '%',))
    print(user_passwd)

get_passwd('Jacob')
```

Note how the username value is now prepended and appended with the `'%'` declared as a string - so forming a string containing wildcard operators within the SQL, not the python string concatentation operator.

Note also how the value is not interpolated into the string, but passed as (part of) a separate argument to the execute()  method to be correctly parameterised and escaped - thus helping with syntax and also dealing with the risks of SQL injection.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html for more details.

---

P.S. I'd question why you're writing a method to retrieve a user's password at all...to have a properly secure environment passwords must not be stored in plain text, but one-way hashed and then never retrieved. To check password validity during login, hash the password again using the same salt and see if it matches the database version. And if the user forgets their password, write a routine to allow them to reset it, not retrieve it.

Comment: Not should, **must**. Use [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) at the absolute least.

Comment: @tadman true. Was not paying full attention to the wording. Amended now.

Comment: Thanks. A properly hashed password is a safe password.

Comment: This solved the problem.
I don't care about the security since it's  only for a practice project

Comment: @JacobPedersen glad it helped you. Please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" (click the tick next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks. P.S. Just because it's a practice project doesn't excuse you from getting into good habits regarding security. Then when you do it for real you won't have to learn the technique all over again. It's so simple and easy to do that there's really very little excuse for not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for like this

```
def get_passwd(user_name):
user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%s'"%user_name)
 print(user_passwd)
```

Call

> get_passwd('Jacob')

Although this is prone to attack.

```
user_name = // assign your parameter in this variable
user_passwd = mycursor.execute('SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name LIKE ?' ,user_name)
```

Comment: Don't suggest quick fixes that don't really solve the problem as the first part of your answer. The second part is the real recommendation. The first is just plain dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add single quote around the %s

```
"SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name LIKE ('%s')"
```

Comment: not if you parameterise the query correctly - and thus avoid SQL injection risks in the process. This version is not secure.

Comment: This a bandage on a much, much bigger problem: [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).